# Indexing dataframe into elasticsearch using Python

Tags: python, parsing, elasticsearch, indexing, mapping

I'm trying to indexing some pandas dataframe into ElasticSearch. I have some troubles while parsing the json that I'm generating. I think that my problem is coming from the mapping. Please below find my code.

```
import logging
from pprint import pprint
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import pandas as pd

def create_index(es_object, index_name):
    created = False
    # index settings
    settings = {
        "settings": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 0
        },
        "mappings": {
            "danger": {
                "dynamic": "strict",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                       "type": "text"
                    },
                    "first_name": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "age": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "city": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "sex": {
                        "type": "text",
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    }

    try:
        if not es_object.indices.exists(index_name):
            #Ignore 400means to ignore "Index Already Exist" error
            es_object.indices.create(index=index_name, ignore=400,     
body=settings)
            print('Created Index')
        created = True
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
    finally:
        return created


def store_record(elastic_object, index_name, record):
    is_stored = True
    try:
        outcome = elastic_object.index(index=index_name,doc_type='danger', body=record)
        print(outcome)
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Error in indexing data')


data = [['Hook', 'James','90', 'Austin','M'],['Sparrow','Jack','15', 'Paris', 'M'],['Kent','Clark','13', 'NYC', 'M'],['Montana','Hannah','28','Las Vegas', 'F'] ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['name', 'first_name', 'age', 'city', 'sex'])
result = df.to_json(orient='records')
result = result[1:-1]
es = Elasticsearch()
if es is not None:
        if create_index(es, 'cracra'):
            out = store_record(es, 'cracra', result)
            print('Data indexed successfully')
```

I got the following error

```
POST http://localhost:9200/cracra/danger [status:400 request:0.016s]

Error in indexing data
RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'failed to parse')
Data indexed successfully
```

I don't know where it is coming from. If anyone may help me to solve this, I would be grateful.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you print value of `result` variable that hold json .

Comment: '{"name":"Hook","first_name":"James","age":"90","city":"Austin","sex":"M"},   
        {"name":"Sparrow","first_name":"Jack","age":"15","city":"Paris","sex":"M"},   
        {"name":"Kent","first_name":"Clark","age":"13","city":"NYC","sex":"M"},  
        {"name":"Montana","first_name":"Hannah","age":"28","city":"Las Vegas","sex":"F"}'

Comment: It seems you want to index multiple documents in a single request. For this you must use bulk request.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove extra commas from your mappings:

```
"mappings": {
  "danger": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      first_name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "age": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "city": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "sex": {
        "type": "text", <-- here
      }, <-- and here
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

It seems that the index is created successfully and the problem is in data indexing. As *Nishant Saini* noted you probably are trying to index several documents at a time. It can be done using [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html). Here is the example of correct request that indexes two documents:

```
POST cracra/danger/_bulk
{"index": {"_id": 1}}
{"name": "Hook", "first_name": "James", "age": "90", "city": "Austin", "sex": "M"}
{"index": {"_id": 2}}
{"name": "Sparrow", "first_name": "Jack", "age": "15", "city": "Paris", "sex": "M"}
```

Every document in the request body must appear in the new line with some meta information before it. In this case metainfo contains only id that must be assigned to the document.

You can either make this query by hand or use [Elasticsearch Helpers](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html) for Python that can take care of adding correct metainfo.

Comment: POST localhost:9200/cracra/danger[status:400request:0.045s] Error in indexing data

Comment: @BillyLeZeurbé OK, if index is already created you should use [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) to store many records at a time as Nishant Saini already noted.

Comment: can you show me how to solve the issue because I didn't find.

Comment: @BillyLeZeurbé I've updated my answer. I hope it will help.